# Cannot migrate in django using mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I'm trying to migrate my data from sqlite to mysql database but when I'm migrating the models, i'm getting the following error:

`RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': (2059, "Plugin http could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is 'http.dll'")`

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Plugin http could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is 'http.dll'")`

what can be the problem?

I'm using Django 4.0.5, python 3.10.2, mysqlclient 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

My Bad....i had http://127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.0.1 in my db configuration.